# upload and scale image without height argument

Tags: php

```
<input type='file' id='inpfile' accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" hidden>
```

I want to upload `jpg, png, gif` images, max width `960px` and update database with new data.

**php**

```
$file = $_FILES['inpfile'];

$filename = $file['name'];
$tempname = $file['tmp_name'];

$arr = explode('.', $filename);
$ext = strtolower(end($arr));

$info = getimagesize($tempname);
$origw = $info[0];
$origh = $info[1];
$mime = $info['mime'];

if ($mime !== 'image/jpeg' and $mime !== 'image/png' and $mime !== 'image/gif') {
    echo "ONLY JPG-PNG-GIF ALLOWED !";
    exit();
}

if ($mime == 'image/jpeg') {$newimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($tempname);}
elseif ($mime == 'image/png') {$newimg = imagecreatefrompng($tempname);}
elseif ($mime == 'image/gif') {$newimg = imagecreatefromgif($tempname);}

if ($origw <= 960) {
    $uniq = uniqid() . "." . $ext;
    $targ = '../images/' . $uniq;
    move_uploaded_file($tempname, $targ);
}

else {
    $finalimg = imagescale($newimg, 960, -1, IMG_BICUBIC);
    $uniq = uniqid() . "." . $ext;
    $targ = '../images/' . $uniq;
    if ($mime == 'image/jpeg') {imagejpeg($finalimg, $targ);}
    elseif ($mime == 'image/png') {imagepng($finalimg, $targ);}
    elseif ($mime == 'image/gif') {imagegif($finalimg, $targ);}
}

list($w, $h) = getimagesize($targ);
$st = $db->query("insert into images (fname, width, height) values('" . $uniq . "', " . $w . ", " . $h . ")");
```

Seems it works, but two questions:

- Is there a shorter way to do this?
- [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php) for imagescale (new height) says:
  `If omitted or negative, the aspect ratio will be preserved.`

I tried:

```
$finalimg = imagescale($newimg, 960, IMG_BICUBIC);
```

And the final image is `960 x 4px` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a shorter way to do this?

When it comes to the GD/image functions: I don't think so. However, you could maybe simplify the `if/else` stuff for determining the image type.

> Documentation for imagescale (new height) says:
>   If omitted or negative, the aspect ratio will be preserved.

You can't omit the third parameter (`$new_height)` when you pass in the fourth (`$mode`). If you want to set the mode, you also need to set the height. So do it like this:

```
$finalimg = imagescale($newimg, 960, -1, IMG_BICUBIC);
```

Comment: And what is then the default `$mode` ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php), the default mode is `IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED`